# Daylight savings and the date_histogram in kibana 4

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to create a graph containing a date histogram. Everything is working except when crossing the daylight savings period. Check the table below for an example, notice the problem with the line of October 31st. Does anyone know a way to overcome this problem and get buckets beginning on each first of the month. The inputs are dates without a time, so for every record the time is midnight.

```
April 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000    11499
May 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000  11850
June 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000 15992
July 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000 14215
August 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000   14178
September 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000    12739
October 1st 2013, 00:00:00.000  14133
October 31st 2013, 23:00:00.000 13653
November 30th 2013, 23:00:00.000    12537
December 31st 2013, 23:00:00.000    14040
```

Just to make things better to debug, this is the executed query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "orderCreationDate",
        "interval": "1M",
        "pre_zone": "+02:00",
        "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if someone has a workaround for this.. I got the same issue.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing. Does the time_zone field support a value that adjusted depending on what the timezone is (like PST, PDT)?